# Debug IE error Object expected

Tags: javascript, object, object-expected

I am trying to debug this error but it does not give me enough info ti figure it out? or does it???

http://c5beta.dealercontrol.net/inventory/1-2l1305517101/Mercedes-Benz_E-Class_E350_White_2010#request-info

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; GTB6; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Fri, 3 Jun 2011 20:53:11 UTC

Message: Object expected
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://c5beta.dealercontrol.net/inventory/1-2l1305517101/Mercedes-Benz_E-Class_E350_White_2010

Message: Object expected
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI:

Message: Object expected
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI:

Message: Object expected
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI:

Comment: Please post the relevant code here rather than linking out to full web pages.

Answer (score 13):

Without even seeing code, my gut tells me that you have a trailing comma somewhere inside an array or object literal.  IE will choke on those with the `Object expected` error, usually at line 1 (which is meaningless).

Something like this:

```
var something = [
  "val1",
  "val2",
  "val3",
  "val4",
];
      ^^^^^
```

Comment: This!  The trailing comma is the bane of every JS developer's existence.  All the other browsers just ignore it - IE wants to crash and burn your entire page because of it.  It can be tough to track these guys down sometimes, so as you write you code, be aware of this ALWAYS.  Whenever you make a new object, it should be part of your habit to check for trailing commas before you move on to other code.

Comment: I concur.  In nearly 100% of instances this is the cause of the trouble in IE.

Comment: Thanks for the reply's I will look through this closely.

Answer (score 2):

Install IE9 and pray it produces the same error. Press F12 to open the developer console which is somewhat capable of doing useful debugging.

Have fun.

Comment: +1 Actually IE8 may give enough information in the developer console too.

Comment: Actually not in this case, @MichaelBerkowski. Example of this error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w1v256eqe6b4si4/Screenshot%202015-05-01%2019.58.04.png?dl=0

Answer (score -1):

You can install 'IEDeveloper' tool onto IE8 or IE7 (i guess you will not using IE6, if you are not lucky enough :)), and debug the page and that will show the exact location where the problem is , shortcut F12