# *ngFor stopped working on IE 11 / Angular 4

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, ngfor

I have this in my in Tabs component that contains list of Tab as its children .

The logic works fine anywhere else except on IE 11.

I have added what is needed for IE11 in polyfills.ts but it did not help .

```
==================================================
exception  
=====================================================

ERROR TypeError: Object expected
   "ERROR"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      @@hasInstance: undefined,
      @@isConcatSpreadable: undefined,
      @@iterator: undefined,
      @@match: undefined,
      @@observable: undefined,
      @@replace: undefined,
      @@rxSubscriber: undefined,
      @@search: undefined,
      @@species: undefined,
      @@split: undefined,
      @@toPrimitive: undefined,
      @@toStringTag: undefined,
      @@unscopables: undefined,
      __proto__: { },
      description: "Object expected",     
      message: "Object expected",
      name: "TypeError",
      number: -2146823281,
      stack: "TypeError: Object expected

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object expected
TypeError: Object expected
   at QueryList.prototype[] 
   at iterateListLike 
   at DefaultIterableDiffer.prototype.check 
   at DefaultIterableDiffer.prototype.diff 
   at NgForOf.prototype.ngDoCheck 
   at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline 
   at checkAndUpdateNodeInline 
   at checkAndUpdateNode 
   at prodCheckAndUpdateNode 
   at Anonymous function (Function code:81:5)",
      Symbol()_m.e3qplm0ag21: undefined,
      Symbol()_n.e3qplm0ag21: undefined,
      Symbol()_p.e3qplm0ag21: undefined,
      Symbol(rxSubscriber)_o.e3qplm0ag21: undefined
   }
```

The html is

```
<li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" (click)="selectTab(tab)" [class.active]="tab?.active"> <a> {{tab?.title}} </a> </li>
```

any idea?

Comment: here is where it is failing
     <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" 
  (click)="selectTab(tab)" [class.active]="tab?.active">
            <a>
                {{tab?.title}}
            </a>
        </li>

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232596/debug-ie-error-object-expected

Comment: any luck? I am also facing the same issue.